# selenium for Google search

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, google-search

I am trying to build a simple function in selenium that given a text brings back all the result from Google. I'm using xpath to find all result elements. Although "//a[@class='l']" works as a legit xpath with firebug the resulting list is empty when I run the code.

```
public void testSearch() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    query.sendKeys("obama twitter");
    query.submit();

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
        WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("gssb_e"));

        if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed()) {
            break;
        }
    }

    List<WebElement> weblinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='l']"));
    for (WebElement suggestion : weblinks) {
        System.out.println(suggestion.getText()+"\n");
        System.out.println("==> "+suggestion.getAttribute("href")+"\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried the same code and it is fetching all the available links on the page.check the below output.

Barack Obama (BarackObama) on Twitter

==> https://twitter.com/BarackObama

Happy birthday ...

==> https://twitter.com/BarackObama/status/291989162670821376

Four more years

==> https://twitter.com/BarackObama/status/266031293945503744

Obama's "Jedi mind meld" gaffe stirs jokes on Twitter

==> http://www.cbsnews.com/8301-205_162-57572120/obamas-jedi-mind-meld-gaffe-stirs-jokes-on-twitter/

Comment: Agreed with HemChe. I can't reproduce your issue. That said, your waiting technique is crude and is the most likely source of your problems. Take a look at [Implicit](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) and [Explicit](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) Waits with [`ExpectedConditions`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html). Play with them, look at SO questions related to them or around the web - you need to master these to be effective with WebDriver.